# Should I use useCallback for a function that updates state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have a function `handleFileSelect` inside a React Component. It does some processing on the input file, and based on that it updates some states, which would trigger a rerender of the component.

But rerenders cause the function to be re-created. So will all the previous processed info be lost?

- So should I use something like useCallback to prevent re-creation of my function?
- And if that is the case, should'nt I do this for most functions?

```js
const handleFileSelect = async(event: ChangeEvent < HTMLInputElement > ) => {

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files ? .length > 0) {

    setFormDisabled(true); // state-update
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (!imageWithinSizeLimit(file)) {
      sendToast('error', 'File size beyond allowed range! Choose a file lesser than 0.5MB')
      clearImageInput();
      setFormDisabled(false); // state-update
      return;
    }

    const valid = await validateImageType(file);

    if (valid) {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
      fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
        // @ts-ignore
        imagePreviewRef.current ? .setAttribute("src", ev.target.result)
      }
      setImageValid(true);   // state-update
      setFormDisabled(false) // state-update
    } 
    else {
      clearImageInput();
      sendToast('error', "We only accept PNG or JPEG files as Avatar images")
      setFormDisabled(false) // state-update
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*all the previous processed info*"

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `handleFileSelect`? It looks like an event listener. "*rerenders cause the function to be re-created*" - yes, but they don't cause the function to be re-executed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.

If you don't need to track your function as dependency or you don't create component inside another component, then you don't need useCallback